# Illegal unicode characters

Tags: php, json, unicode, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to send document.sdf (json) to Amazon Cloud Search. Everything works fine until there are some special characters

```
Found Unicode characters that are not legal for Cloud Search:\n Illegal Unicode character '\u0002'\n Illegal Unicode character '\u0010'\n Illegal Unicode character '\u0001'\n Illegal Unicode character '\b'
```

The error comes out of this piece of the text:

```
...sadad<br \/>\n;color:G\u0002% k\u0010>\u0001\b? X_? p>", ...
```

These are from document.sdf that is generated by PHP script and `json_encoded`

The original text of the above:

> ;color:G% k>? X_? p>

Comment: Those are control characters, any reason why they would be in your text string?

Comment: @datasage this comes from a user generated content column. How to escape control characters?

Comment: You probably should remove them. Should be able to detect and remove them with a regex statement when generating the document.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worthwhile to strip all of the invalid characters from the text with a regex like:

```
[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF]
```

But when I ran into a similar issue, the problem was just that I wasn't specifying the character encoding explicitly when doing my POST, e.g.:

```
$curl = curl_init($cloudsearch_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
            array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8')); //Defaults to ISO10646 (I think) without this
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_exec($curl);
```